# WriteLine Method

Tags: c#, .net

I have a log file (.txt) which has information as below:

```
Filename1 -  A3332NCDER
Filename2 -  B3332NCDER
Filename3 -  B1222NCDERE
Filename4 -  C1222NCDER
Filename4 -  C1222NCDERE
```

Each line holds the filename and the corresponding ID. Now I am picking the ID’s and assigning it to the List.

```
char[] delimiters = new char[]{'\n','\r','-'};

IList<string> fileIDs = File.ReadAllText(logFileName)
         .Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
         .Where((lineItem, index) => index % 2 == 1)
         .Select(lineItem => lineItem.Trim())
         .ToList();
```

I am writing to the log file as below:

```
using (StreamWriter logFile = new StreamWriter(logFileName, true))
{
    logFile.WriteLine(fileName + "   - " + fileID);
}
```

This works fine.I am curious to know why WriteLine method adds both `\n` and `\r`.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a historical baggage from the time when we used type writers. To end the current line and begin a new line, you would have to do two things:

1. Move the carriage back to the start of the line - `"Carriage Return"` or `CR` for short
2. Move the paper up so you get a blank line to write on - `"Line Feed"` or `LF` for short

Of course, none of this is necessary on a computer, but old habits die hard...

Different operating systems use different line ending characters (or sequence of them) but for the big systems:

- Windows: CR + LF
- Unix/Linux/OS X: LF
- Old Macs (v9 and earlier): CR

For more information and a bigger list of OS specific line endings, see wikipedias article on [Newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

In .NET, there is a static property called [Environment.Newline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) that contains the appropriate line ending string based on which system your application is running on.

---

Regarding your code, you could simplify it a bit and just call [File.ReadAllLines()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) and you'll get an array containing all lines. That way you don't have to bother with String.Split etc.

Or if you are ok with a .NET 4 dependency, use [File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) which will lazy read one line at a time so you don't have to store the entire file in memory. Or thirdly, you can do the old but faithful [ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) method:

```
string line;
while ((line = myFile.ReadLine()) != null) 
{ /* do stuff to line here */ }
```

Answer (score 3):

> The default line terminator is a string whose value is a carriage
>   return followed by a line feed ("\r\n" in C#, or vbCrLf in Visual
>   Basic).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdf6yhx5.aspx

The terminator can be changed by setting `Console.Out.NewLine`, eg:  `Console.Out.NewLine = "\r\n\r\n";`

Answer (score 0):

That's why it's WriteLine. If you don't want the standard line terminator \n\r then use Write

Answer (score 0):

It is a Microsoft standard line ending to have '\r\n'. It comes from the days of typewriters. Originally, the 1st character was to move *down* one line, and the 2nd character moved to the beginning of the *current* line. Thus, taken together, you get to the beginning of the next line.